# what does "cast the approval" mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

I don't understand the meaning of the word "cast".

Specifically, for example, in this phrase:

> "Cast the approval"

I've never seen this phrase before.

Comment: Can you please tell us where you saw this phrase, and if possible provide a complete sentence and/or a link to it?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like either a typo of some sort, or you have mis-identified which words belong where, i.e. this _isn't_ a phrase.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly common to use cast in this context, but perhaps not immediately obvious what it means.

When we use the word "cast" as a verb, it's hard to put ones finger on a *cover-all* definition, but lets start of with the google definition:

> **Cast** *[literal]* to throw (something) forcefully in a specified direction.

You may have heard the phrase:

> "Cast your vote"

I bring this up just because it's a much more common use of the word, which has the same general meaning as *cast the approval*, which I haven't heard used as a phrase before.

Taking the literal definition we can ascertain the *metaphorical* definition by just replacing the verb (throw).

> I.e. *cast your vote* would be to vote [forcefully] in a specified direction.

I put *forcefully* in brackets as I don't think this is necessarily true in the metaphorical definition.

Now, to answer your original question I would assume (although it's hard to say without further context) that it means:

> to approve [forcefully] in a specified direction

This is why it feels unnatural. Approving is already a "direction". However, common phrases also include *cast your mind back*, and *cast doubt [upon something]*. So it seems that the rigorous definition has been warped with time to just mean that it is doing the verb which the phrase describes. Therefore I would say:

**To cast approval is just to approve.**

Of course, this is mostly speculation on my part. [As you can see](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cast), definitions seem to not be very rigorous.